# How to fit image to next column in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, containers

I want to create a rather simple banner with bootstrap 3 but struggle with the image size of a logo.

This is my code:

```
  <div class="container well">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">
        </div>
          <div class="col-xs-9">
        <address>
        Company<br>
        Address<br>
        Contact<br>
        </address></div></div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <address>
        <strong>Person 1</strong><br>
        Name<br>
        Contact<br>
        </address></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <address>
        <strong>Person 2</strong><br>
        Name<br>
        Contact<br>
        </address></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://www.bootply.com/PuYXFCgqAs

The logo should always have the same height as the company adress. As soon as the screen gets too small the columns should wrap onto a new line like this:

- logo + company adress
- person 1
- person 2

In my code, the image is too high from the beginning and scales pretty weird on a smaller screen.

It seems so easy but my bootstrap skills are pretty basic. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't your end goal exactly what you have at the moment? On desktops the logo is inline with everything, and on mobiles it is only inline with the address. You could always just specify a fixed `width` and `height` for the logo if you don't want it to resize as the screen gets smaller.

Comment: As soon as I drag my window smaller than 992px (small devices) the image gets very large. It should not get bigger than the adress at any time. I think I will go with a fixed height then. Is there any way to find out the exact height of my address? Doesn't this heigt change depending on the device?